# Webpack: Is this the intended behavior?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I am using the webpack-simple template with VueJS v2.x. First, running "npm run build" fails. Running "npm run dev" works. If I have an error in my source code before running "npm run dev", the command fails.
I apologize for not showing any code but i don't need help fixing my code. I want to know if thats how webpack works. If there is an error it spits a useless error message. Here is the error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v7.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! gg@ dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --inline --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221226505
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gg@ dev script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --inline --hot'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the gg package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --inline --hot
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs gg
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls gg
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was from node and npm. I'm running on win10 and was using node v7.10. After downgrading to 6.9 everything started working properly